# replace a string with regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have been learning regular expression for a while but still find it confusing sometimes
I am trying to replace all the

```
self.assertRaisesRegexp(SomeError,'somestring'):
```

to

```
self.assertRaiseRegexp(SomeError,somemethod('somestring'))
```

How can I do it? I am assuming the first step is fetch 'somestring' and modify it to somemethod('somestring') then replace the original 'somestring'

Comment: Could you provide more context? Your question appears to be "How can I edit my source code?" Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Hi Rob: Yeah, I have a python code base and am trying to use another python program to edit the existing python source codes based on the above rule, Thank you

Comment: And is your goal to learn how to do use Python to do it, or is your goal to get the change done?

Comment: My goal is to learn to use python re module to get it done. I kinda know how to use string.find to get it done but I am assuming using re module will have a much easier solution?

Comment: Maybe find: `(self.assertRaiseRegexp\(SomeError,)('somestring')\)` replace `$1somemethod($2))` but I'm guessing there is more to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your regular expression

```
#f is going to be your file in string form
re.sub(r'(?m)self\.assertRaisesRegexp\((.+?),((?P<quote>[\'"]).*?(?P=quote))\)',r'self.assertRaisesRegexp(\1,somemethod(\2))',f)
```

this will grab something that matches and replace it accordingly. It will also make sure that the quotation marks line up correctly by setting a reference in `quote`

there is no need to iterate over the file here either, the first statement "(?m)" puts it in multiline mode so it maps the regular expression over each line in the file. I have tested this expression and it works as expected!

## test

```
>>> print f
this is some
multi line example that self.assertRaisesRegexp(SomeError,'somestring'):
and so on. there self.assertRaisesRegexp(SomeError,'somestring'): will be many
of these in the file and I am just ranting for example
here is the last one self.assertRaisesRegexp(SomeError,'somestring'): okay 
im done now
>>> print re.sub(r'(?m)self\.assertRaisesRegexp\((.+?),((?P<quote>[\'"]).*?(?P=quote))\)',r'self.assertRaisesRegexp(\1,somemethod(\2))',f)
this is some
multi line example that self.assertRaisesRegexp(SomeError,somemethod('somestring')):
and so on. there self.assertRaisesRegexp(SomeError,somemethod('somestring')): will be many
of these in the file and I am just ranting for example
here is the last one self.assertRaisesRegexp(SomeError,somemethod('somestring')): okay 
im done now
```

Answer (score 0):

A better tool for this particular task is sed:

```
$ sed -i 's/\(self.assertRaisesRegexp\)(\(.*\),\(.*\))/\1(\2,somemethod(\3))/' *.py
```

`sed` will take care of the file I/O, renaming files, etc.

If you already know how to do the file manipulation, and iterating over lines in each file, then the python `re.sub` line will look like:

```
new_line = re.sub(r"(self.assertRaisesRegexp)\((.*),(.*)\)", 
                  r"\1(\2,somemethod(\3)", 
                  old_line)
```

Comment: Thank you,I have used grep but didn't know about sed

Comment: And, if you want to write a Python program to do it, I've added the single line of `re.sub` that you might need.

Comment: you should escape the "." in self.assert... because as of now this will also work with selfAassert... because the `.` matches all characters